# Suppose that $X$ is a nonempty subset of a set $Y$. Show that $S_X$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_Y$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Suppose that $X$ is a nonempty subset of a set $Y$.
Show that $S_X$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_Y$.

Updated idea:

Define $f:S_X\rightarrow f(S_X)$ by
$$f(\sigma x)=\sigma x,\forall x\in X$$
$$f(\sigma y)=y,\forall y\in Y-X$$
where $\sigma \in S_X$

Let $\sigma,\tau \in S_X$
Suppose $f(\sigma)=f(\tau)$
Then $\sigma x=\tau x,\forall x\in X$
and $\sigma y=\tau y=y,\forall y\in Y-X$
Hence $\sigma=\tau$ and $f$ is injective.

Next it is clearly that $f$ is surjective

Since $f(\sigma \circ \tau)=f(\sigma)\circ f(\tau)$
$f$ is homomorphism.

Note that $f(S_X)=\{\alpha\in S_X |\alpha(y)=y,\forall y\in Y-X\}$
(i)$1\in f(S_X)$
(ii)$\alpha,\beta \in f(S_X)\implies \alpha\circ\beta^{-1}y=y,\forall y\in Y-X$
Hence,$f(S_X)\leq S_Y$

Comment: I take it that $S_X$ is permutations on the set $X$?  Think carefully about the difference between the claim that $S_X$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_Y$ and your following statement that $S_X$ *is* a subgroup of $S_Y$.

Comment: @hardmath Does $X\subset Y \implies S_X \leq S_Y$? since S_X itself is a group.

Comment: A permutation on $X$ is a 1-to-1 function from $X$ to $X$.  A permutation on $Y$ is a 1-to-1  function from $Y$ to $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a permutation $\sigma$ on $X$. Now extend $\sigma$ to a permutation $f(\sigma)$ on $Y$ by setting $f(\sigma)(y) = y$ for all $y \in Y - X$. Then $f$ is an injective morphism and $f(S_X)$ is a subgroup of $S_Y$.

Comment: @hardmath You're right, edited.

Comment: So now we are defining a function $f:S_X\rightarrow S_Y$ by $f(\sigma x)=\sigma x$ for $x\in X$ and $f(\sigma y)=y$ for $y\in Y-X$ where $\sigma \in S_X$?

Comment: Right. You just fix the points of $Y - X$ to extend $\sigma$.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you have a look on that? Thanks